# How to control scrolling sound of uipicker?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

How to control scrolling sound of uipicker? Any available sample code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way.  That being said:

```
[myPickerView setSoundsEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Peter said, there's no public way to do this. However, if it's really critical you could implement your own picker-type object. Basically, all you need to do is create a UITableView and customize the cells as you like. Then create an image to add as a UIImageView subview that's the same size as the table. At its simplest, all you need is a little bit of gradient fade-to-black at the top and bottom so the cells of the table appear to fade in/out. You could also add a bit of a frame around the table, or anything else really, as you like.

If you take a look at a picker and think of the wheels as just UITableViews with a gradient at the top and bottom, you'll see that the curved effect is just that simple. If you look closely as you scroll the cells offscreen, you can see that they never change shape; they just fade out.

As for the sounds, you could then use any of the UIScrollViewDelegate and UITableViewDelegate methods to monitor when the "wheel" moves and check to see where the table cells are on-screen. Perhaps when a cell passes the mid-way point, you play your custom sound.

It would definitely take a little bit of work to implement this, but is certainly possible if it's critical for your app.